# Mask Sender Address in wp_mail() in Wordpress

Tags: wp-mail

I am using `wp_mail()` function to send email to user in WordPress. I want to hide sender name like I want to mask sender email as `noreply@gmail.com` etc.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#using-headers-to-set-from-cc-and-bcc-parameters):

> To set the “From:” email address to something other than the WordPress
>   default sender, or to add “Cc:” and/or “Bcc:” recipients, you must use
>   the $headers argument.
>
> $headers can be a string or an array, but it may be easiest to use in
>   the array form. To use it, push a string onto the array, starting with
>   “From:”, “Bcc:” or “Cc:” (note the use of the “:”), followed by a
>   valid email address.

This example from the [User Contributed Notes](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/#user-contributed-notes) shows you how to use it:

```
<?php
// assumes $to, $subject, $message have already been defined earlier...

$headers[] = 'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: John Q Codex <jqc@wordpress.org>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: iluvwp@wordpress.org'; // note you can just use a simple email address

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
?>
```

As you can see, you can set the From name and address by adding `'From: Me Myself <me@example.net>'` to the `$headers` argument of `wp_mail()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Using the two ‘wp_mail_from’ and ‘wp_mail_from_name’ hooks allow from
>   creating a from address like ‘Name email@address.com‘ when both are
>   set. If just ‘wp_mail_from’ is set, then just the email address will
>   be used with no name.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_from_name

As the other answer mentions, you can use the headers argument to specify the From name and address, but if you look at the source code comments you'll see it is supported now only for legacy reasons.